# sbt parsers and dynamic completions

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to build a git command parser in sbt.

The goal of the parser is not so much to validate the actual git command but rather to provide auto-completion within the sbt console.

The parser relies on bash completion scripts, so it's fair to say that generating the completions is fairly expensive as a process has to spawn every time. That's why I'd like to minimize the number of call made to the bash-completion process.

I have a working solution, that looks like this:

```
def autoCompleteParser(state: State) = {
  val extracted = Project.extract(state)
  import extracted._

  val dir = extracted.get(baseDirectory)

  def suggestions(args: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
    // .. calling Process and collecting the completions into a Seq[String]
  }

  val gitArgsParser: Parser[Seq[String]] = {

    def loop(previous: Seq[String]): Parser[Seq[String]] =
      token(Space) ~> NotSpace.examples(suggestions(previous): _*).flatMap(res => loop(previous :+ res))

    loop(Vector())

  }

  gitArgsParser
}

val test = Command("git-auto-complete")(autoCompleteParser _)(autoCompleteAction)
```

However I have two problems:

- the completion process is called for every character, which is more than I'd like
- the potential completions seems to be passed as a parameter to another round of completions, which means even more calls to the external process.

My question is the following: **how do I tell sbt to reuse/cache the completions he has got for the rest of an argument without calling the process for each character?** For example:

completions for 'git a' are:

*dd        m         nnotate   pply      rchive*

Then completion for 'git ad' are:

*d*

without the need to call the suggestions method again. I have tried to implement an ExampleSource, but I could not obtain the behavior I was looking for from it.

Any pointer would be welcome. And if someone understands why the potential completions seems to be passed into another completions round, that would help me a lot too.